# Match multiple conditions in Array#reject

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a directory. I want to select all files (but no directories) that don’t have an `.mp3` extension. This works:

```
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }.reject { |f| File.extname(f) == '.mp3' }
```

But if possible, I’d like to do it in a single swoop. I’ve tried the following:

```
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").reject { |f| File.file?(f) && File.extname(f) == '.mp3' }
```

But it doesn’t work. It does ignore non-`.mp3` files, but it still include directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reject all files that are a directory *or* have the `mp4` extension. Just write it like this:

```
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*")
   .reject { |f| File.directory?(f) || File.extname(f) == '.mp3' }
```

Or you might want to negate the condition and use `select` instead. Select everything that is a file *and* does not have the `mp3` extension:

```
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*")
   .select { |f| File.file?(f) && File.extname(f) != '.mp3' }
```